# Notice: Undefined variable: rank in C:\xampp\htdocs\ujicoba\svd7.php on line 420

Tags: php, arrays, assignment-operator

i find it in my code

> Notice: Undefined variable: rank in C:\xampp\htdocs\ujicoba\svd7.php on line 420
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: frobA in C:\xampp\htdocs\ujicoba\svd7.php on line 427
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: frobAk in C:\xampp\htdocs\ujicoba\svd7.php on line 429
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: matrixProduct in C:\xampp\htdocs\ujicoba\svd7.php on line 37

it is source code php in line 420 :

```
 $rank = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($W); $i++){
        if(round($W[$i], 4) > 0){
            $rank += 1;

        }
    }
```

than code line 427 - 429 like this :

```
$q = 0.9;
    $k = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < $rank; $i++) $frobA += $W[$i];
```

than error code line 33 - 42

```
if($colsA == $rowsB){ 
        for($i = 0; $i < $rowsA; $i++){
            for($j = 0; $j < $colsB; $j++){
                for($p = 0; $p < $colsA; $p++){
                    $matrixProduct[$i][$j] += $matrixA[$i][$p] * $matrixB[$p][$j];//error code here in variabel $matrixProduct

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

so how to fix my problem, i so confuse to trace syntax. any idea or solution?

Comment: if(isset($matrixProduct[$i][$j]) and isset($matrixA[$i][$p]) and isset($matrixB[$p][$j])){
                    $matrixProduct[$i][$j] += $matrixA[$i][$p] * $matrixB[$p][$j];
};

Comment: ok thanks for solution, it work 100%